# Laravel Error al Editar Detalle

Tags: php, laravel

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `asignaturas_detalles` where `asignaturas_detalles`.`alumno_matriculacion_id` = 1 and `asignaturas_detalles`.`alumno_matriculacion_id` is not null and ((`0` = 5 and `1` is null and `2` is null and `3` is null and `4` is null)) limit 1)

Ese es el error que me muestra alguien que pueda ayudarme, abajo dejo el mi update

```
public function update(AlumnoMatriculacionRequest $request, AlumnoMatriculacion $matriculacion){
        $alumno = Alumno::all();

        $file = null;
            if($request->hasFile("file")) {
                $file = Uploader::uploadFile("file", "matriculacion");
            }
        try {
            $input = $request->all();

            $results[] = array( "final1" => $request->input("final1"), "final2" => $request->input("final2"));
            //dd($results);
            $matriculacion->asignaturas()->updateOrCreate($results);
        
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return $e->getMessage();   
        }

        session()->flash(
            "message", [
                "success",
                    __("Matricula del alumno actualizada con exito")()
                    ]
                );
            return redirect(route('matriculacion.index2'));
        }
```

Comment: y la estructura de la tabla y la entidad? o tenemos que adivinarla ?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].